# Service s = new ServiceImpl() - Why you are doing that?

Tags: java, interface

I just read this article [SERVICE S = NEW SERVICEIMPL() - WHY YOU ARE DOING THAT?](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/service_s_new_serviceimpl_why)

Would like to know your views about it.. wondering what you will name it other than 
impl?

Comment: @bart-kiers Copied the blog title as is.. Thanks for correction :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Impl` suffixes are a naming [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). It denotes the lack of effort on the developers part to descriptively name a `Class`. This is the flip side of the `IService` interface naming [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) as well. Both practices reek of laziness or poor design choices or both. Both are code smells, that should alert the developer that something isn't right.

The fact that the code says `interface Service` and `class MyService implements Service` should be enough, anything else is a [tautology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tautology). Even more so with today's advanced Java IDEs.

If you have a `Service` interface, then name the implementations descriptively. `Service` is generic, which for interfaces is good. `HttpService`, `AuthenticationService` are specific which for classes is good. Self documenting for the most part in both cases.

If you can't give unique descriptive names to your interfaces and classes, you are doing it wrong.

In the `Mocking` argument, assuming that the real classes are in `com.company.app.service`. Mock implementations should be in their own `com.company.app.service.mock` package, probably in a different directory structure with the Test classes, as in Maven, which will allow them to have the same names as the non-Mock classes, and still document that they are Mocks for testing only, and not pollute the name space of the production code and make it easy to not-include that code in the deployment.

Comment: Generally if you have Users (say hibernate entity) in system then interface service name is UserService (provides contract-save, update etc) and implementation is UserServiceImpl.

Comment: @Premraj: I would argue it should be `UserHibernateService`.

Comment: or better `HibernateUserService` to be consistent with the naming convention of the `UserService` interface. `Impl` is always a code smell and bad form.

Comment: It depends. I do: `UserHibernateService extends HibernateService implements UserService`

Answer (score 1):

It's a common practice (probably due to a lack of imagination) among service providers. They provide you with the Service interface and their implementation. By providing you with the interface, they still allow you to create your own implementation.

Regarding the "why name is XyzImpl", I'll stick to a lack of imagination/effort.

Comment: i agree its a good practice if you are writing opensource API or API which will be used by unknown developers.. but in project this isn't the case and specially if its limited module and not exposed outside of module.. but people still consider this best practice and provides one interface with one implementation even for unexposed Service

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the interface describes the functionality and the implementation describes how that functionality is achieved.

A classic example is the Collection library:

`List` is understandable even for non-techies
`ArrayList` is a `List` that is implemented with a backing Array
`LinkedList` is a `List` that is implemented with linked nodes

This naming scheme is simple and understandable.

Another example could be DAOs:

a `PersonDAO` is a DAO interface for accessing Person objects
a `JdbcPersonDAO` is a `PersonDAO` implemented using JDBC
a `JpaPersonDAO` is a `PersonDAO` implemented using JPA
etc.

Now with services, it's slightly different. Services are usually not aware of the technology underneath, so there is usually nothing that uniquely characterizes one implementation.

`Service > ServiceImpl` is one way to deal with this problem, another one is `IService > Service`, which is equally awful. An improvement would be the convention found in the Maven code base: `Service > DefaultService`, where `DefaultService` is obviously the default implementation of `Service`. How about that for a reasonable naming scheme?

Comment: @Sean-Patrick-Floyd Hmm. that sounds good

Comment: I would argue that `DAO` suffix is wrong as well, there should be a `DAO` package that all the classes go in, then you don't have to repeat the `DAO` suffix tautology over and over. That is unless `DAO` is an `interface` or `class` that `Person` implements or extends.

Answer (score -1):

The better practice is to have a factory that instantiates and returns an implementation based on some configuration (with sane defaults).  For example

```
Service s = ServiceFactory.getInstance().newService();
```

This allows you to use different implementations at runtime.

Comment: you still have to *name* that concrete implementation something. The question is about the tautology naming conventions that are so prevalent in the Java community.

Comment: and that using service locator, not DI